# AngularJS - Conditionally apply style using ng-style to first element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I have an object of styles and I need to set another css style only for the first element.
I created a directive especially for that, but it doesn't work

I will appreciate your help!

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row" ng-style="rowCss" ng-repeat="top in gridObj" ng-zero>
```

```js
$scope.rowCss = {
    "height" : rowAndSquareHeight,
    "padding-top": baseLine
}

editorApp.directive('ngZero', ['$document', '$parse', function($document, $parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        $(element).css({"padding-top" : "0px"});
    };
}]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are having this issue because cssRow is overriding your styling in the directive ngZero. You can use others solutions as susggested ; btw, the argument element is already a jqLite wrapped element, so no need to wrap it in jQuery again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="row" 
    ng-style="{ true : rowCss }[$first]" 
    ng-repeat="top in gridObj">
    ...
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHu6eu0pgB74UkXTRjkN?p=preview)**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a directive for that. ng-repeat scope exposes an property `$first` in the repeat scope which is true for first element. You can define a class for the first row and use ng-class to apply it

`ng-class="{'my-first-class':$first}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index to track the 'n'th element. Not sure if the directive has been created to solve this issue but could just use ng-attr-style="{$index==1 ? '"padding-top" : "0px"}'}"

Also you should not manipulate HTML or refer to presentation/css in Controllers.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the **ng-if** - new in version 1.1.5, for manipulating CSS styling conditionally.