# Animating first element of collection with angular on data change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am creating simple front end web application that is consuming REST with angular.js. I have collection of five elements provided by angular controller, and WebSocket which reloads collection on message.

mycontroller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var protocol = 'some protocol';
var address = 'some address';
var callsAddress = 'some other address';
var socket = new WebSocket(address, protocol);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.loadData();
        socket.open();
        console.log('initialized');
    }

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        $scope.loadData();
    };

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $http.get(callsAddress).success(function(data) {
            $scope.calls = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

And here is index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="mycontroller.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MyController">
        <div class="text-center bg-primary" ng-repeat="call in calls">
            <h1>{{call.number}}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each time data in collection is changed (that is when data is loaded), I want to animate first element of the collection, e.g. gradually change background color of div element from red to blue. How can I achieve that kind of behavior?

I tried to do something with ng-if, but only thing I managed is to remove first element from the collection, so I'm not really sure that ng-if is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. Let's separate them to clarify solution:

1. Changing style only to first element in ng-repeat
2. Changing style (i.e. animate) on change

Ad 1: [AngularJS - Conditionally apply style using ng-style to first element in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176185/angularjs-conditionally-apply-style-using-ng-style-to-first-element-in-ng-repe)

Ad 2: See https://plnkr.co/edit/mZI9Iv6ZR4Wvg8cHEst1. You can add changeColor() here:

```
    $scope.loadData = function() {
    $http.get(callsAddress).success(function(data) {
        $scope.calls = data;
        changeColor();
    });
};
```

Just combine 1 & 2.

Comment: I have managed to change the color, but transition is not working for some reason, color instantly changes from one to another, I have also added -webkit-transition but with no luck